# What is the best way to implement event handling on multiple list of child components in svelte?

Tags: event-handling, svelte

Let's say I have a to-do list. Each list item has a delete button which will delete the item from  list array if clicked. Now we can use these methods.

**1.**

```js
//store.ts

export type Item = {
    text: string;
    id: string;
}

export const items = writable<Item[]>();
```

```html
<!-- Item.svelte -->
<script>
    export let id; //I don't want to use id on the html elements. As anyone can change it from inspection tool.
    export let text;
</script>

<div> {text} <button on:click={() => {
    //handle click event
}}> close </button> </div>
```

```html
<!-- Items.svelte -->
<script>
    import Item from "./Item";

    const items = [
        {
            id: 1,
            text: 'Turn on pc'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            text: 'Open VS code'
        }
    ];
    
</script>

{#each items as item}
    <Item id={item.id} text={item.text} />
{/each}
```

**2.**

```html
<!-- Items.svelte -->
<script>
    import Item from "./Item";

    let container;

    function handleClick(node){
        node.onclick = (evt) => {
            const target = evt.target;
            //handle event
       }
    }


    const items = [
        {
            id: 1,
            text: 'Turn on pc'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            text: 'Open VS code'
        }
    ];
    
</script>

<div use:handleClick>
{#each items as item}
    <Item id={item.id} text={item.text} />
{/each}
</div>
```

I somehow need to get the Object reference we used to build the element inside {#each} block.
But as I said I'm not interested using id on html that we can use to grab the element we clicked on.

Comment: "I don't want to use id on the html elements. As anyone can change it from inspection tool." You seem to have a misunderstanding of how web applications security works. It does not matter what happens in the browser, you have to *validate everything on the server* regardless. People can send whatever innocuous or malicious requests they want, without using a browser in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Just forward the event and use a closure in the `#each` to pass the item.

In `Item`:

```html
<button on:click >...</button>
```

In parent:

```html
{#each items as item}
    <Item id={item.id} text={item.text} on:click={() => handleClick(item)} />
{/each}
```

Comment: But at the end there will be elem.$on(...) event listener for each component in the compiled js. So it would be the same as Example 1. I've shown.

Comment: Not quite, the handler within the component does not have access to anything outside.

Comment: So is there will be only one event listener on the whole program? [except the svelte system one's if they use any]

Comment: There will be one per item, why do you care? Have you measured that this actually has any impact?

Comment: No, I was actually building something for low end devices. So I was wondering how much it will affect the app if there are so many items. In simple terms we can just listen to click events on the parent and then find out the target by HTML elements id and take action. My concern was is there any way to get the object or variable we used to generate the html, in our case 'item'. There is no such performance issue with a todo app. It was just for asking about a little part of my program.

Comment: If you want to use delegation, you have to store the item ID on the element, one way or another. I would only do that if there really is a good reason to.